# Matrix Multiplication with a matrix consisting of a single shifted row

Tags: time-complexity, matrices, fast-fourier-transform

I have the following question (prefacing this with the fact that this is a question from an exam, I am currently studying but am stumped so reaching out for help).

> The answer to the following question must **NOT** use Strassen's algorithm and every arithmetic operation is considers as $O(1)$.
> Given two square matrices $A$ and $E$ (both $n\times n$) where $A$ fulfils the next unique property, provide the best efficient algorithm to calculate the matrix multiplication. Note that if $T(n)$ is the time complexity of the algorithm, it must old that $T(n)=o(n^3)$ (i.e. $T(n)/n \rightarrow 0$ must hold true).
> The unique property that $A$ holds is that, the first row is $(a_0, a_1,...,a_{n-1})$ the $i$-th row is $(a_{n-i+1},...,a_{n-1},a_0,...,a_{n-i})$.
> Example, the third row will be: $(a_{n-2},a_{n-1},a_0,...,a_{n-3})$.

Given the exam itself there are only several topics to ask questions about, and this being the last question I believe that this is to do with FFT - **but it might not be** (this is just an educated guess considering the structure of the exam).
It was easy for me to come up with solutions that do not hold the complexity requirement of $o(n^3)$, but no solution I thought of solved it in the required time.

The main issue I ran into when trying anything is that when I try to do the multiplication I have to either shift the column I'm working on or the row I'm using - a total of $n$ times.

Here's an example of something I thought at a high level:

1. Select the first row of $A$ and mark it $v$
2. Compute FFT value for each of the $n$ shifts and store in an array of $n$ elements named $F$
3. For each column $c\in E$:
   3.1 For each value $f\in F$:
    3.1.1 Compute $FFT(c)$
    3.1.2 Interpolate the polynomial $C$ that is the convolution of the $f$ and $c$
    3.1.3 The sum of the $n$-th elements will be the element in the given column and relevant index of $f$ and index of $c$ and matrix

As you can see, it requires $n^3log(n)$ and not $<n^3$

I would appreciate if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong, or where I'm going wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to think of a way to calculate $A c$ in time $O(n\log(n))$. Hint: you only need a single convolution.